# JS - can a linter catch type errors?

Tags: javascript, types, lint

What seems to make many Java peeps anxious about JS is its "cool dad" nature; it doesn't care if you smoke pot or hang out with your friends until 2am. Without that structure, it's impossible to check for type safety at "compile time"... or is it?

Of course, javascript has types, but it's not strongly typed. That being said, a human reading the following excerpt will notice that this is going to throw a runtime exception:

```
function f(anArray) {
    "use strict";
    anArray.push("hi");
}
f(5); //runtime exception for sure
```

We can see this as programmers because, even though types aren't explicitly declared *(e.g. int c;)*, we can gather various other characteristics to deduce its type *(it's a number without quotes)*. It seems like there's an algorithm (such as a decision tree) that could easily infer the type of a given object.

The essence is that in a dynamically typed language, types exist, but their use and conversions are *implicit*.  My question, then, is:

*Is it plausible that linters could use implicit conventions to determine what the intended type of a method is, and warn about a potential runtime error at "lint time"?*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are typecheckers for javascript that can catch this error, yes, but they're typecheckers not linters.

Comment: How can you know there is no `Number.prototype.push` method at runtime? :-P

Comment: Haha, sounds like an answer to me.  I guess I was confused on the semantic meaning of a linter.

Comment: That _is_ a problem.  But, since linters also enforce convention, they could strictly warn against extending built-in prototypes or even using extended features of top-level prototypes.

Comment: To rebut my own comment, though, you couldn't really expect a linter to know all the available methods in, say, a `jQuery` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code inspectors like linters or type checkers can only go "that far" in analysing code to spot type incompatibilities.

Consider for instance this code:

```js
function f(a) {
  return a%2 ? [a] : false;
}
x = [];
for (var i=1; i < 10; i+=2) {
  x = f(i).concat(x);
}
document.write(x);
```

This will not be a problem; but it would have been if *i* had started at 2 instead of 1. In general the value passed to *f* could be the result of a complex algorithm, and a code inspector would have to actually run the code to know the result. This of course is not the idea of such a tool, and so in practice it is only possible to find trivial cases of type incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that you take a look at [Tern](http://ternjs.net/), you can install it into your text editor (or just run it as a executable), and it will attempt to determine the type of a variable in a certain scope, and offers tools such as code completion, method suggestions (based off of determined type), function argument hints, etc. It's not perfect, but works very well based on JavaScript's limitations.